# How to modify the citeyear command to include several clickable years in parenthesis?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a `References.bib` file that contains two entries like these:

```
@article{hartmascolell,
    author = "Sergiu Hart and Andreu Mas-Colell",
    title = "Bargaining and Value",
    journal = "Econometrica",
    volume = "64",
    number = "2",
    pages = "357 -- 380",
    year = "1996",
    url = "https://doi.org/10.2307/2171787"
}

@article{hartmascolell2,
    author = "Sergiu Hart and Andreu Mas-Colell",
    title = "Potential, Value, and Consistency",
    journal = "Econometrica",
    volume = "57",
    number = "3",
    pages = "589 -- 614",
    year = "1989",
    url = "https://doi.org/10.2307/1911054"
}
```

I then have my main document, in which I’m defining a custom style `citeyearpar` for the years of my citations to be clickable hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

% REDEFINING CITEYEAR

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{hartmascolell}'s \citeyearpar{hartmascolell2,hartmascolell} approach...

\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

I would like to have (1989, 1996) rather than (1989), (1996). **How can I do that?** Also, how can I change the delimiter (i.e., to get “(1989; 1996)” rather than “(1989,1996)”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{References.bib}

% REDEFINING CITEYEAR

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {\bibopenparen}
    {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
    {;}
    {\bibcloseparen}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{hartmascolell}'s \citeyearpar{hartmascolell2,hartmascolell} approach...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The standard idiom here would be `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printdate}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}` (or `\addsemicolon\space` if you want output different from the standard `\multicitedelim`). Commands like `\bibhyperref` should never be used "bare", they should be used only via field formats. This makes sure that they don't clash with punctuation produced with the punctuation buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want author-year citations, you should be using `\parencite*` for a parenthetical citation that omits the author name. For the 'compressed' output you want a `-comp` style like `authoryear-comp`.

The advantage of this approach is that it also works well when you change the citation style. Plus it is slightly more semantic in the markup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\Citeauthor{knuth:ct:a}'s \parencite*{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} approach\dots

\Textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b} showed\dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth’s (1984, 1986) approach... Knuth (1984, 1986) showed...]