# Only cite the year, and the year has parentheses around it

Tags: biblatex

I am so new to Latex and biblatex.

Here is the problem.
`\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

my goal is like

> (1964)

it only has year and no any authors
but, with current command, I only got

> Gouldner et al., (1964)

or

> 1964

or

> (Gouldner et al., 1964)

So, is there any way for me to get it?

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and provide some code so that people can see what you do and test it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I have got the way. just \parencite*{}. I am so dumb

Comment: If you want proper APA style, you should call `biblatex` as `\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}` and not as `\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}`. The option `sorting=nyt,` sets a sorting that is not strictly speaking real APA. `sortcites` is redundant. If the guide that recommended this piece of code also recommended `\DeclareLanguageMapping` it is seriously outdated (`\DeclareLanguageMapping` has not been required for at least three years now).

Answer (score 1):

Many `biblatex` styles define a starred version of some of their commands that omits the name part of the citation. This is usually the go-to command if you have mentioned the author name manually somewhere and only need the label part of the citation.

If you want to print the publication year, there is `\citeyear` (which normally does not include any disambiguation letters, but curiously does with `biblatex-apa`).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

Lorem \parencite{sigfridsson}

Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}

Lorem \nptextcite{sigfridsson}

Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}


ipsum \autocite*{sigfridsson}

ipsum \parencite*{sigfridsson}

ipsum \textcite*{sigfridsson}

ipsum \nptextcite*{sigfridsson}

ipsum \cite{sigfridsson}


dolor \citeyear{sigfridsson}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) Lorem Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998 Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998 ipsum (1998) ipsum (1998) ipsum Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) ipsum 1998 ipsum Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998 dolor 1998]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605017/35864,